# Changing the affinity of a Console C# program

Tags: c#, console-application, affinity

In [this page](https://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/how-to-set-the-processor-affinity-programatically/), the following code is an example for changing the affinity of the current process:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process myProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Console.WriteLine("ProcessorAffinity: {0}", myProcess.ProcessorAffinity);
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)3;
        Console.WriteLine("ProcessorAffinity: {0} ", myProcess.ProcessorAffinity);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

But the output for me is:

> ProcessorAffinity: 255
>
> ProcessorAffinity: 255

meaning that the affinity is not changed. What's the problem? And how can I change the affinity?

Comment: Change `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)3;` to `myProcess.ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)3;`

Comment: Also, wrap `myProcess` in `using` statement, like this: `using (var myProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess()) { .. }`

Comment: @vasily.sib How can wrapping be helpful?

Comment: @nano, `Process` instance is helding some unmanaged resources, so if you not disposing it correctly - your app will leak. This is also recommended [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

Comment: Is your program running in elevated mode *(administrator mode)*? You can not change affinity without this.

Comment: @Julo, as I know, there is no need in elevated permissions, when you changeing affinity of your own process. Why do you think, that he can not change affinity without this?

Comment: My bad. I only know, you need to have elevated permissions to change affinity, but I forgot, that this might not be the case for my own process. *(I only tested this with application1 changes affinity of application2)*.

Comment: This kind of sounds a little X/Y'ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChetanRanpariya mension in his comment, the issue is because you changeing `ProcessorAffinity` of one process object (returned from the **second** call of `Process.GetCurrentProcess()`) and checking it in another (returned from the **first** call of `Process.GetCurrentProcess()`). Here is corrected sample:

```
using (var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ProcessorAffinity: {currentProcess.ProcessorAffinity}");
    currentProcess.ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)3;
    Console.WriteLine($"ProcessorAffinity: {currentProcess.ProcessorAffinity}");
}
```